# Button click event fires on page reload

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have problem with adding event to button element.

**Problem**:

Function supposed to be event handler fires on page reload and when I click button.

I want it to fire only when button is clicked.

This is my code:

**index.html file**:

```
<form id="contact_form">
    (Some form fields here)
    <button id="form_submit" value="send">Send</button>
</form>
<script src="contact_form.js"></script>
```

**contact_form.js file**:

```
var submit_button = document.getElementById('form_submit');

submit_button.addEventListener("click", test_click_event());

function test_click_event()
{
     alert("Button clicked");
}
```

I'm using Chrome to debug.

Comment: Why not just use `onClick` instead?

Comment: @pattyd You mean onClick event instead of Click, or adding `<button onClick="somefunction();">` in HTML?

Comment: yes that is what I mean... it would be so much easier

Comment: I still dont know what you meant. Read my comment again, I asked "something or something" :)

Comment: If you mean adding event inside html tag - I just want to keep js totally separated from HTML.

Comment: Why would you want to do that though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
submit_button.addEventListener("click", test_click_event);
```

brackets are not needed

Answer (score 1):

() brackets call to function execute remove them or use this:

```
var submit_button = document.getElementById('form_submit');

    submit_button.addEventListener("click", function(){test_click_event();});

    function test_click_event()
    {
         alert("Button clicked");
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ruddog2003/qYwLp/)

Comment: They are called parenthesis ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the brackets but you need to add an anonymous function.
See here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp

For example:

```
submit_button.addEventListener("click", function (){
    test_click_event();
});
```